# How to generate JUnit HTML report in Netbeans 7.1?

Tags: netbeans, junit, junit4, netbeans-7

How can I generate JUnit HTML report in Netbeans 7.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can run JUnit graphically in NetBeans, I don't think there is a way to export the report.  However, NetBeans has great integration with Ant.  You can use the [junitreport](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) Ant task to generate the HTML report.